# Streaming video content from handheld devices (android, ios) to Ubuntu

Tags: vlc, streaming, totem, dlna

I'd like to receive media content from various devices to an Ubuntu desktop. I've seen some Totem plugin were available in the past for using it as a DLNA receiver, but I cannot find them anymore. The same for VLC, I've seen tutorials which shows it can act as DLNA player, but again I cannot find the same features in the latest version (2.2.1).

Can anyone suggest a DLNA player, something which can receive a stream from LAN?